How can i make the margin smaller without making the png image change its size?
enter image description hereenter image description here
Hi, i'm new to Android Studio XML, i need to make the margin of my PNG img smaller so it's make me easier to constraint other view, but when i change the hitbox the size of image changing too, so i need to know how please, ty before.
i tried to modify the margin smaller, but the image changing too

You can't.  The size of the image is the picture plus the margin.  You could make the view smaller to cover the margin.
